# Kivy Background Image didn't launch

Tags: kivy

I've got this code in kivy and the console said me error on the 'source' line...

Why ? I don't understand, because on my school computer and my android phone, it works very well !

```
<Jeu>: #BoxLayout
canvas:
    Rectangle:
        source: 'fond.png'
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
```

Can you help me ?

EDIT:

```
Traceback:
[WARNING           ] [Image       ] Unable to load image <C:\Users\Aurélien\Desktop\WordDown\PROGRAMME COMPLET\fond.png>
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Kivy\kivy\kivy\lang.py", line 1806, in _build_canvas     setattr(instr, key, value)
   File "instructions.pyx", line 337, in kivy.graphics.instructions.VertexInstruction.source.__set__ (kivy\graphics\instructions.c:6499)
   File "context_instructions.pyx", line 360, in kivy.graphics.context_instructions.BindTexture.source.__set__ (kivy\graphics\context_instructions.c:7160)
   File "C:\Kivy\kivy\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 442, in __init__     self.filename = arg
   File "C:\Kivy\kivy\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 631, in _set_filename     mipmap=self._mipmap, nocache=self._nocache)
   File "C:\Kivy\kivy\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 371, in load     im = loader(filename, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Kivy\kivy\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 150, in __init__     self._data = self.load(filename)
   File "C:\Kivy\kivy\kivy\core\image\img_pygame.py", line 41, in load     im = pygame.image.load(filename)
 pygame.error

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Aurélien\Desktop\WordDown\PROGRAMME COMPLET\main.py", line 78, in <module>
     WorDown().run()
   File "C:\Kivy\kivy\kivy\app.py", line 766, in run     root = self.build()
   File "C:\Users\Aurélien\Desktop\WordDown\PROGRAMME COMPLET\main.py", line 73, in build
     jeu = Jeu()
   File "C:\Users\Aurélien\Desktop\WordDown\PROGRAMME COMPLET\main.py", line 54, in __init__
     BoxLayout.__init__(self)
   File "C:\Kivy\kivy\kivy\uix\boxlayout.py", line 103, in __init__     super(BoxLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Kivy\kivy\kivy\uix\layout.py", line 63, in __init__     super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Kivy\kivy\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 173, in __init__     Builder.apply(self)
   File "C:\Kivy\kivy\kivy\lang.py", line 1566, in apply     self._apply_rule(widget, rule, rule)
   File "C:\Kivy\kivy\kivy\lang.py", line 1619, in _apply_rule     rule.canvas_root, rootrule)
   File "C:\Kivy\kivy\kivy\lang.py", line 1810, in _build_canvas     '{}: {}'.format(e.__class__.__name__, e))
 kivy.lang.BuilderException: Parser: File "C:\Users\Aurélien\Desktop\WordDown\PROGRAMME COMPLET\wordown.kv", line 6:
 ...
4:    canvas:
5:        Rectangle:
6:            source: "fond.png"
7:            pos: self.pos
8:            size: self.size
 ...
 error:
```

Comment: Please post the exact traceback that you get.

Comment: Excuse me, I'm french and don't know the word traceback. The console just said me "error" and put a > in the line "source"... Do you want more code ?

Comment: The traceback means all the output you get in the console from that error. In python code the important part is often labelled 'Traceback (most recent call last)'.

Comment: If I understood, this is all the console Traceback : http://textup.fr/116691kh

Comment: @AurélienPitaut I've actually never seen an error like that in kivy. Any idea what is different on you school computer/android phone? And why the error is in french?

Comment: And, just to be sure, have you checked that the source file (fond.png) exists? (Francais - It's not the best: Avez-vous verifier que le fichier fond.png existe?)

Comment: Because I'm french ! I really don't know why it doesn't work on my pc... And I'm sure and have checked that the file 'fond.png' exists.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is in your .kv file.
you have this:

```
canvas:
    Rectangle:
        source: "fond.png"
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
```

you should try this:

```
canvas:
    Rectangle:
        Image:
            source: "fond.png"
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```